# Angular handle query params with multiple question marks

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps, deep-linking

I am trying to handle the email confirmation link that is automatically generated by Firebase into my Ionic/Angular app on the web platform.
I have tried with the Deeplink cordova plugin (docs say it supports web) but returns "cordova_not_available" error.
I have tried with the capacitor App plugin but it returns a default empty string on browser.
I have tried calling `location.toString()` but the link contains **multiple question marks** in query parameters values, and everything from the second question mark on gets removed.
The link generated by Firebase looks like:

```
https://example.com?link=https://example.com?apiKey%3D{myApiKey}%26mode%3DverifyEmail%26oobCode%3D{theCodeIneed}%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://example.com/email-confirmed%26lang%3Den&apn=com.example.myAppName&amv&ibi=com.example.myAppName&ifl=https://example.com?apiKey%3D{myApiKey}%26mode%3DverifyEmail%26oobCode%3D{theCodeIneed}%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://example.com/email-confirmed/%26lang%3Den
```

But what I get from `location.toString()` (the best so far) is just:

```
https://example.com?link=https://example.com
```

so there is no way for me to get the **oobCode** param, which is what I need to confirm that the user owns that email address

Is there a way to get the full link?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found that by setting `handleCodeInApp = false` in the actionCodeSettings parameter of the sendPasswordResetEmail or sendEmailVerification Firebase methods, the link automatically generated by Firebase happens to have just one question mark (I don't know why), thus it can be managed through `location.toString()` to retrieve the oobCode.